# CSS not work without ".min.css" as the name format

Tags: css, django

I'm currently using bootstrap on django but somehow one of the CSS below does not work

- this doesn't work: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.css
- this works!! https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

I ensure them they have the same version of bootstrap. This is my static file code on my base template `html`:

```
<!-- THIS DOES NOT WORK -->
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}">
```

```
<!-- THIS WORKS -->
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
```

my static dirs contains both of the file.

does anyone know why the `.min.css` works? or any other possible causes on why the `.css` file does not work? I want to use the `.css` not the min.

Comment: What kind of error do you see in the browser console?

Comment: I agree with @Razenstein, there is no reason why one should work and not the other.  What does your browser console show?  The code is the same.  I'm sure you have your reasons for not using the min, which should be exactly the same save for comments, readability and white-space.  Having min files is common to reduce file size.  Now the links link to the CDN, but have you also downloaded the files into your static folder, which I think is what you did?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap and many other web base components are using a compressed version of the CSS and JavaScript files, that is why you are seeing min on the file name.

Recommendation:
Use this code to load bootstrap instead of yours:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


{% load bootstrap5 %}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript %}

</head>
```

Comment: True that many web CDN's use a compressed min version, but apologies of my ignorance, but I have *never* seen this code as a way to load bootstrap.